# How to border the two-line content of my text [HTML]

Tags: html, css, border

I want to add a border all around my html text, but I can't manage to do this. I have tried this method, but the border is split when it meets the `<br>`:

```
<div id='page' style='width: 600px'>
  <h1><span style='border:2px black solid; font-size:42px;'>Actually looking <br>for a job in IT</span></h1>
</div>
```

Does someone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put style='border:2px black solid; font-size:42px;' on the h1 tag instead of the span tag

Comment: Thank you, is there a way for the border to fit to the text ? Here there is space between the text and it

Comment: you have to play with the line-height property if you want the border right on the text